# angular hide base href from URL

Tags: angular, api, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I had an Angular project and a web api host in the iis under same domain.
The angular build files i put in folder /web, while api publish files are in /api folder.
When i build the angular,i use `ng build --base-href "/web/" --prod`.and in the web.Config file had rewrite it `<action type="Rewrite" url="/web/" />`.
When i browse the web site, the url is `http://localhost:8090/web/login`. How can remove or hide the **web** in url, so the url become `http://localhost:8090/login`?

Comment: there are a lot of questions and answers already on SO. Try using search function. In meantime this could help? https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/tips-for-running-an-angular-app-in-iis/

Comment: it looks like it would work if you just remove the --base-href and <action rewrite from your configurations

Answer (score 1):

To hide it, just change base href.

```
ng build --base-href "/" --prod
```

This will work and solve the issue.